# Encriptar datos al enviar formulario PHP

Tags: php, html

Amigos tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<form class="ps-form--visa" action="" method="post" style="width: 50%;padding-left: 6%;">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Card number</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" id="numeroTarjeta" name="numeroTarjeta" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titular Tarjeta</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" id="titularTarjeta" name="titularTarjeta">
         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Experation Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="MMAA" id="fechaExpiracion" name="fechaExpiracion">
         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>CVV</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" id="codigoSeguridad" name="codigoSeguridad">
         </div>
         
         <div class="form-group submit">
            <button class="ps-btn ps-btn--fullwidth">Pagar</button>
         </div>
      </form>
```

El cual corresponde a un formulario previo al pago de un articulo X en un sitio ecommerce​, ahora bien desearía que cuando el usuario de click en "Pagar" los datos de su tarjeta sean encriptados para luego ser desencriptados en el archivo PHP que efectúa la conexión con el banco.

Comment: Esa no es ni de cerca la forma segura de trabajar con tarjetas de crédito / débito /etc. Te sugiero que busques información sobre pasarelas de pago, como [Stripe](https://stripe.com/es), [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/es/home/), [Amazon Pay](https://pay.amazon.es/), entre otras. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comentario de @MauricioContreras debes tomarlo muy en cuenta, sobre todo la última línea, ya que, independientemente de como lo guardes, así sea el método de encriptación mas seguro (??), no va a evitar que el momento de la transferencia de los datos por medio del formulario sea **HACKEABLE.**

Debes tener en cuenta dos cosas antes de adentrarte en este tipo de situaciones...

1.- La mejor manera de tratar con información delicada es a través de un protocolo seguro y certificado, como SSL.

2.- Al Cesar lo del Cesar... deja que todo lo que tenga que ver con tarjetas de crédito sea manejado por una institución aprobada para ello, es decir, un banco o un merchant autorizado y certificado.

Existen muchos medios seguros para hacer interfases de operación con los servidores bancarios, pero en todos ellos, la parte de las T.C. es manejada por la institución bancaria. Ellos gastan MILLONES de dólares en sistemas y personas dedicadas EXCLUSIVAMENTE a dar seguridad a sus servidores, cosa que nosotros no tenemos, y cuando de dinero se trata es mejor estar bien protegido...

Entiende una cosa... **NI el banco, NI tu cliente** van a perder dinero porque tu desarrollo tenía un problema de seguridad que provocó algún desfalco o fraude... **TE VAN A HACER PAGARLO A TI.**

Así que mejor busca una solución que te deje fuera de estas responsabilidades. Yo personalmente manejo 3 diferentes formas de pago con tarjeta:

1. PayPal
2. 2Checkout
3. Azul del Banco Popular(banco dominicano)

Dependiendo de la necesidad específica, decido cual de estos usaré... pero **NUNCA** considero hacer algo así yo solo...